# ¿Cómo puedo distinguir si un gerundio actúa como verbo o adverbio?

Tags: gramática, categorías-gramaticales

Tengo dificultad distinguiendo *cuándo un gerundio actúa como adverbio o verbo*.  Por ejemplo en la oración:

> Pablo **está durmiendo**.

Entiendo según el artículo [28.12c](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OGwbTCNFgzWxywZt) de la RAE que esto constituye una perífrasis verbal. Por lo tanto ***asumo que durmiendo*** es el verbo auxiliar y por ende el gerundio ***está actuando como verbo*** (¿o me equivoco?).

Entonces en la oración:

> Me **divierto cantando**.

***Asumo que cantando esta actuando como adverbio*** describiendo lo que le parece "divertido" (¿o estoy equivocado?)

¿Alguien puede confirmar si estoy correcto o equivocado?

Aún más importante es si pudieran ayudarme a entender cuándo el gerundio actúa como verbo y cuándo como adverbio para que pueda distinguir entre cada caso. (Me siento bastante perdido.)

De antemano, ¡gracias!

Comment: Prueba rápida que se me ocurre: si el verbo en *-ndo* puede anteceder él verbo flexionado, funciona como adverbio, casi contrario, es elementu perifrástico. «durmiendo Pablo está» suena fatal, pero «cantando me divierto» mucho menos. Otra prueba podría ser por medio de la conjunción «mientras». Fíjate que "Pablo está/lleva mientras duerme» no refleja el sentido del ejemplo, pero «me divierto mientras canto» sí

Comment: (vaya, qué cosas me ha metido el autocorrector)

Answer (score 2):

Dice la NGLE (27.1d) que

> Mientras que el infinitivo puede ser nominal o verbal, en ambos casos de modo productivo, el gerundio se suele construir como verbo, aunque esporádicamente se lexicalice como adjetivo, adverbio o locución adverbial (…). En cuanto forma verbal, el gerundio admite sujetos, sean expresos (…) o tácitos (…). Admite también el gerundio los demás complementos que corresponden al verbo, sean directos (*leyéndolo*), indirectos (*hablándole de ese modo*), de régimen (*refiriéndose a su trabajo*), circunstanciales (*trabajando en la oficina*) o atributos (*permaneciendo alerta*), entre otros.

Con base en esta aclaración, se puede testear si el gerundio tiene una función verbal o adverbial. En el primero ya vemos que forma parte de una perífrasis. Esa perífrasis es inseparable, ya que *Pablo está* significa algo muy diferente a *Pablo está durmiendo*. Tan diferentes son semánticamente que es fácil imaginarse una conversación donde se contrasta una con la otra:

> *—Hola, ¿está Pablo?*
>   *—Sí, Pablo está, pero está durmiendo.*

En cuanto al segundo ejemplo se puede ver que el gerundio es verbal agregándole complementos verbales:

> *Me divierto cantando.*
>   *Me divierto cantando canciones.* (objeto directo)
>   *Me divierto cantándoles canciones a mis hijos.* (objeto indirecto)
>   *Me divierto cantándoles canciones a mis hijos en el jardín.* (complemento de lugar)

… y así hasta el infinito. Estos añadidos demuestran que el gerundio cumple función verbal.

En cuanto al gerundio como adverbio o frase adverbial, la NGLE (27.2) dice que

> El gerundio puede adquirir, como se ha explicado, las funciones
>   gramaticales que corresponden al adverbio, pero son muy limitados los
>   contextos en los que acepta otros comportamientos característicos de
>   esta clase de palabras. Destaca entre todos ellos el adverbio de grado
>   *tan*, que en la lengua literaria aparece como modificador de un número reducido de gerundios.

A continuación la NGLE da ejemplos del tipo de *tan callando*, *tan temblando de miedo*, etc., que hoy en día son más bien literarios.

También se citan (y esto sí es interesante) gerundios lexicalizados en adverbios como *pitando*, con el significado de "deprisa, precipitadamente" (la construcción típica es *salir pitando*; en la región rioplatense se usan *rajando* o *carpiendo* con el mismo sentido, en frases como *me sacaron carpiendo* = "me expulsaron a las apuradas"). Se usa también como adverbio el gerundio *volando* con verbos de movimiento (*el tiempo se me fue volando*).

Es decir: el gerundio con función adverbial existe, pero es bastante raro, y no es productivo sino lexicalizado (hay que considerarlo como una palabra con un significado particular, no como una forma más del verbo del cual deriva).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y perdona pero solo para aclarar, si entiendo bien me estas afirmando que en ambas oraciones el gerundio actua como verbo.  ¿He entendido correctamente?  Si ese es el caso, ¿podrias compartirme un ejemplo donde actue como adverbio?

Comment: Disculpa, ¿podrias darme un ejemplo donde el gerundio actue como adverbio entonces?

Comment: ¡Mil perdones! No pude contestar la primera vez y ahora veo que faltaba parte de la respuesta. Acabo de agregar lo que dice la Gramática sobre los gerundios como adverbios.